How to identify pending transactions that call a specific contract function in Ethereum?
I need to monitor pending transactions in the Ethereum network to identify if any of them call a specific function in a contract. The function could be called directly by a transaction or indirectly via another contract. This means a transaction might call another contract which in turn calls the target contract function. I want to detect both direct and indirect function calls in pending transactions. It would be thankful if you provide a sample code.

I'm not sure if you can just implement this, It will require a lot of resources to build and run it. It would be better to relay on private service provider for such data, like Achlemy maybe or other similar provider. For indirect pending transaction it will be more complicated and not sure if they support such thing

Check Status of the transaction
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('YOUR_INFURA_OR_ALCHEMY_URL');

// ABI and contract address
const contractAddress = 'YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS';
const functionSignature = web3.utils.sha3('yourFunctionName(parameters)').substring(0, 10);

web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', async (error, txHash) => {
  if (error) console.error(error);
  else {
    const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
    if (tx && tx.to && tx.to.toLowerCase() === contractAddress.toLowerCase()) {
      if (tx.input.startsWith(functionSignature)) {
        console.log(`Direct call detected: ${txHash}`);
      }
    }
    // For indirect calls, further analysis is required using tracing tools like Geth's debug_traceTransaction
  }
});

Check Status

This script listens for pending transactions and checks if they call a specific function in the target contract. Once a transaction is mined, you can check its status using web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt:
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, (err, receipt) => {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
} else if (receipt && receipt.status) {
console.log(Transaction ${txHash} was successful.);
} else {
console.log(Transaction ${txHash} failed.);
}
});

For indirect calls, you'll still need to use transaction tracing
tools to analyze the internal calls made by the transactions.


